# UISplitViewControllerDelegate willChangeToDisplayMode

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I've implemented this method successfully but how do you get the initial display mode of a split view controller?  This method only gets called when the display mode of the split view controller changes but not when it's first displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question, you simply ask the split view controller what its display mode is via the property `displayMode`

For example:

```
UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode currentDisplayMode = self.splitViewController.displayMode;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had just assumed that wouldn't work on startup like the collapsed property but it does report the correct mode in -application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:.